# How to reinitialize Angular 4 sub component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am building an angular web app, and I have a navbar and sidebar component which their respective selector tag is used to render it to the app.component.html. Then I have a login component which I use the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to render it. So when I load my app which the default path is the login component, I want the Navbar and Sidebar component to either not to initialize when on the login page or reinitialize on successful login. This is because I will have to display the name on the navbar which is stored in the sessionStorage, which return null on the login page (session not set yet). I have tried using css to display it to none but the navbar component still initialize on the login page. Hope I can find some answers.

App.Component.html

```
<!-- Here the current details of the user appears and update can be made-->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="green" data-image="assets/img/olam.png">
        <!--
     Tip 1: you can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="blue | azure | green | orange | red | purple"
     Tip 2: you can also add an image using data-image tag
 -->
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
            <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and garbage solution would be using a `*ngIf="isLoggedIn"` on both side and nav bars. But, don't use this one, this one is evil and ugly.

A proper approach for this problem would be taking advantage of sub routes feature of Router. Instead of using the same template for the whole application, use a major level route to hold login and restrict areas.

For example, say that your `app.component.html` has only the `router-outlet` like so:

App.Component.html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Furthermore, you would need to increase the login page template with the required stuff:

LoginPage.Component.html

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Notice that you can add a custom bar for the login page if you like. In addition, you can use a sub routes set to switch among login, register and remember password.

Finally, you are up to create the restrict are template:

Restrict.Component.ts

```
<div class="sidebar" data-color="green" data-image="assets/img/olam.png">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-panel">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

In this subroute, the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` would switch trough the sub pages of the restrict area; for example: dashboard, users, fees and accounts.

Route tree:

```
+- /
    |
    +- /login
    |    |
    |    +- /sign-in
    |    |
    |    +- /sign-up
    |    |
    |    +- /recover-password
    |
    +- /restrict
        |
        +- /dashboard
        |
        +- /users
        |
        +- /fees 
        |
        +- /accounts
```